# ORDER BY after two LEFT JOINs

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, left-join

I have a query like below

```
SELECT veh_year FROM table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2
   ON table1.veh_year = table2.veh_year
  LEFT JOIN table3
   ON table1.veh_year = table3.veh_year
  ORDER BY table3.some_other_column;
```

I am seeing an error at the ORDER BY keyword

`ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
01791. 00000 -  "not a SELECTed expression"`

How can I order by table3.some_other_column?

Comment: If you want to ORDER BY a column, it  needs to be part of the rowset returned from the SELECT. It's difficult to ORDER BY something that isn't there, and your SELECT only returns `veh_year FROM table1`. How is it supposed to sort by `table3.some_other_column` when you've not fetched that column to sort on? Common sense: you can't sort by something that isn't there, just like you can't sort the currency in your wallet when your wallet is empty.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. That explained the error I am seeing. Please post it as an answer

Comment: Is this specific to oracle only? I can order by columns that aren't selected out in SQL Server easily. Here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc4db/1

Comment: @Sam, no @Ken's comment is incorrect: you **can** order by a column that isn't in the `select` clause in Oracle - e.g. `select ename from emp order by sal`.  When I attempt the query above in Oracle 12C I get a different error: `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`, which makes sense as all 3 tables have a `veh_year` column.

Comment: @yalkris: your simplified SQL example does not exhibit the problem (in 12C anyway - I created tables called `table1` etc. to check).  Please check and correct the SQL to accurately reflect the issue.  What Oracle version are you on?

Comment: The error you got not because of OREDY BY ... you can try this sample  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8241d/3   which is working fine, if order by column name not in select list???  YOu have to Provide sample data and expected data to figure out whats going wrong

Comment: Does you query contains `distinct` keyword? Usually this error appears in queries with `distinct`, and in such cases Ken's answer become correct.